# Asus doesn't stay connected to any wifi

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, wireless-networking

For some odd reason when I'm at home my laptop will stay connected for an hour before disconnecting, then when I try to reconnect it will say "cannot connect to this network" but once I restart my modem then my laptop will reconnect for another hour before doing it again. I am a bit tired of restarting my modem 7 times a day. Even when I connect to public WiFi, my laptop will stay connected for 20 mins then it will do the same thing so I'll have to restart my laptop in order to connect again.

Answer (score 0):

Probably an issue related to the LAN DHCP lease time. In Command Prompt type ipconfig /all and search for Lease Expires field.

If the time is set to 1 hour, then you can change it accessing the LAN settings from the setup of your modem-router. If you don't know how you can find this info on the manufacturer's website.

https://www.howtogeek.com/179700/beginner-geek-how-to-configure-your-router/